# What is in this code that is causing Script error?

Tags: python

```
if (blue_percentage > (red_percentage * 0.49)) and \
   (red_percentage < ((blue_percentage / 1.44) + 1)) and \
   (red_percentage > ((blue_percentage / 4.35)-1) and \
   (blue_decimal > green_decimal) and \
   (red_decimal > green_decimal):
    print "<div>The hue is: <b>Purple</b>.</div>"
```

It says that the

```
:
```

is an invalid syntax.

If I take out the line

```
       (red_percentage > ((blue_percentage / 4.35)-1) and \
```

the program works just fine. Am I causing some kind of contradictory statement or something? I cannot see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  (red_percentage > ((blue_percentage / 4.35)-1) and
```

is missing a closing `)`

If one is more familiar with the code/application, one may be able to simplify this big expression more, but for now, just as a simple way to break this down and make it more manageable you could try something like shown below.

Notice that I placed the whole expression in parenthesis *eliminating* the need for those pesky `\` line continuation markers as recommended by [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

*NOTE*: I'm not saying this is an ideal solution, just a way to manage the complexity until you can figure out a better way to factor out the relevant expressions.

```
cond1 = blue_percentage > (red_percentage * 0.49)
cond2 = red_percentage < ((blue_percentage / 1.44) + 1)
cond3 = red_percentage > ((blue_percentage / 4.35) - 1)

if (cond1 and cond2 and cond3 and 
    (blue_decimal > green_decimal) and  
    (red_decimal > green_decimal)):
    # do stuff ...
```

You could use the `( )` around your big expression in the if-statement even now  w/o changing anything in your code and easily get rid of the `\` characters - they can be another source of problems at times.

Comment: Ohhh, thank you very much. There were so many () to deal with that I totally missed one.

Comment: @AjEntity Well, easy to happen with all of those parenthesis :-) Best to have an editor that does parens-matching for you -- helps minimize these sort of problems

Comment: @Aj: Actually, what would be much better is to simplify that `if` statement. More than one line of conditions is typically too much to grasp.

Comment: @AjEntity NiklasB is right about this .. definitely better to simplify that expression

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing parenthesis in the line:

```
(red_percentage > ((blue_percentage / 4.35)-1) and \
```

It should be

```
(red_percentage > ((blue_percentage / 4.35)-1)) and \
#                                             ^
```

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. Everyone seems to have noticed this except for me. Thank you very much though.

Comment: @AjEntity not that it's striking, we just could easily guess it from the error message. This is why they're required in such questions :) next time you'll know what to look for.